# Adding/Casting LinkedList<Superclass> to LinkedList<Subclass>

Tags: java, casting, linked-list, addition

I have following problem. In a directory structure, the abstract class `FSElement` is extended by it's subclasses `Directory`and `File`.
Every `Directory`has a `LinkedList<FSElement> children` to fill with respective child files and directories.
In my problem I want to fill a `LinkedList<Element> subDirs` only with the directories from `children`, however `.add()` only allows `FSElement`to be added.

How can I cast this `FSElement`to a `Directory`and add it to the linked list? Any help is appreciated.

```
public class Directory extends FSElement {

    // Fields
    private LinkedList<FSElement> children;
    public FileSystem fileSystem;
    private LinkedList<Directory> subDirs;

[...]

    public LinkedList<Directory> getSubDirectories(){
        for(int i=0; i < children.size(); i++) {
            if(children.get(i).isDirectory()) {
                this.subDirs.add(children.get(i)); // ERROR occurs here
            }
        return this.subDirs;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is in the question: casting. Cast `children.get(i)` to Directory. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html. Also, make subDirs a **local** variable: there is no reason for this list to become larger and larger every time you call getSubDirectories(). And each call should return a new list. Use `List<Directory>`  as the return type, and use an ArrayList as the implementation: LinkedList is slow and should almost never be used.

Comment: this.subDirs.add((Directory) children.get(i))